# List of followers and recordings of smule

Tags: json, api

How to get list of recordings, followers etc of a smule user as JSON?
I figured out to get using https://www.smule.com/'USERNAME'/followers/json but it only retrieves max 500 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Recordings are available at https://www.smule.com/'USERNAME'/performances/json

You can only fetch a certain amount of data each time, but you can use the next_offset value to get the next batch, by appending the next_offset value as a query string names offset (https://www.smule.com/'USERNAME'/performances/json?offset=25).

I haven't found a way to get more than 500 followers. I'm assuming the website will only show 500 followers on the page, even if there is more.

Answer (score 1):

Only like this - see examples:

```
/following/json?offset=0&size=0&limit=25 - first page<br>
/following/json?offset=25&size=25&limit=25 - second page<br>
/following/json?offset=50&size=50&limit=25 - third page<br>
```

etc while list in `json` will no be empty

I noticed limit can be `maximum` 25 - in the site they use 24.